# Why is redirect_to not working in create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails beginner here,
Somehow I can't find a way to redirect a user after creating a record.

I've this controller:

```rb
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product successfully created' }
      else
        format.html { render :new, notice: 'Error' }
      end
    end
  end

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :quantity, :status, :image)
  end
```

I've tried some variations such as `redirect_to product_path(@product)` or removing the `format` block, nothing worked. The model and form for submitting values seems to work (validations are passed, records are saved).

Logs:

```rb
Parameters: {"..."}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT ....
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in 'admin?'
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in 'block in create'
  Product Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 ...
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in 'block in create'
  Product Create (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO ...
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in 'block in create'
   (55.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in 'block in create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/4137
Completed 200 OK in 65ms (ActiveRecord: 59.3ms | Allocations: 4974)
```

Something is preventing the redirection (I still have the `notice` message after changing page), but the controller, the form, the model, and the logs looks ok to me.
Does anyone has an idea about what could be responsible here ? Any help would be gratefully appreciated !

Comment: Solution : add `local: true` to my form (+ an opportunity to discover XHRs).
From Rails API : _:local - By default form submits are remote and unobtrusive XHRs. Disable remote submits with local: true._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `form_with` helpers in Rails 6, then they are by default `XHR` forms and they will expect a template with `js` format. To make them respond to `html` format, add `local: true` option.

```
<%= form_with(model: @product, local: true) do |f| %>
```

From Rails guides,

> `:local` - By default form submits are remote and unobtrusive XHRs. Disable remote submits with local: true.

More info - [form_with options](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with-label-form_with+options)

Hope that helps!

Comment: It does help ! It must be a better solution to implement AJAX instead of disabling XHR forms, but I'll do it later :).
Have a great day